# Bitbucket Android pipeline always failed on gradlew

Tags: docker, gradlew, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use Bitbucket Pipelines for my Android project.

There is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` :

```
image: javiersantos/android-ci:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
          - chmod +x ./gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

When i am running my pipeline, i have this error :

> + chmod +x ./gradlew
>
> chmod: cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory

What i missed in my pipeline configuration ?

Comment: Could you share your directory layout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cd` into the folder that contains your `gradlew` file, if it is not in the root folder of your Git repository. You can check where is your `gradlew` file in the Docker build machine, by checking the [`$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html) environment variable, or listing the files:

```sh
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo "The current folder is: $PWD"
          - echo "The git repo root folder is: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR"
          - echo "The files in the git root directory are: $(ls -la)"
          - echo "The folders in the git root directory are: $(echo */)"
          - echo "The gradlew file is at location: $( find . -name "gradlew" -type f -print0 | xargs )"

          - echo "Setting current working directory to subfolder"
          - cd MyProject # This should contain your 'gradlew' file

          - chmod +x ./gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```